# Getting developer mode enabled on Hisense Laser TV

Tags: android, tvos, television

Does anyone know how to enable developer mode on Hisense Laser TV?
Trendy approach to enable developer mode (like clicking 7 times on Build in Device Info menu) doesn't work.

I tried to open the menu but not clickable Build option there.